# How to Use LWUIT Bitmap Fonts?

Tags: lwuit, bitmap-fonts

i'm trying to use LWUIT BitmapFonts in J2ME Applications for Persian Language ... Please Help Me How i do this Work ...

with the best regards .

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Persian Language font in your system. Now, persian language
   will be available in resource editor.
2. Create font in resource editor after selecting the installed font. Now, bitmap font will be created.
3. Import that font in your app and use it.